# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Insert mode to tell vim that I don't want to be inside a comment any more?

Tags: vim, autocommenting

When I write `//` comments in Java, and press Enter, vim helpfully adds a `//` to the beginning of the next line.

```
// This is the first line of my comment <CR>
// <-- these were added automatically by auto-comment.
```

As I say, this is helpful behaviour (I use `//` for multi-line comments to make it easy to comment out large blocks of code with `/*...*/`, and use `/**...*/` only for Javadoc comments).  But when I've reached the end of a comment, I have to press the backspace key three times to get rid of the `//` at the beginning of the line that I now no longer want.

Is there a keyboard shortcut from Insert mode that can tell Vim that I'm no longer writing a comment?  Or do I have to write my own?

Comment: `CTRL-U` in insert mode deletes everything before the cursor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Vim cannot guess your thoughts (yet), you have to tell it explicitly when a new line does not continue a multi-line comment.

A straightforward solution is to simply delete the autoinserted comment leader with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> in insert mode. See [`:h i_CTRL-U`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-U).

This key combo also works in most terminals, by the way.

In case you don't like autoinserted comment leaders at all, you can disable them with the command `:set fo-=ro`. See [`:h 'formatoptions'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatoptions%27).