# inserting a new line below a comment in vim?

Tags: vim

While inserting a new line below a comment in vim, the result tends to insert a `"` at the start of the new line.  It's probably a simple solution or reason why this is happening, but I am unable to find an exact solution.

Comment: `<C-u>` clears the line if you dont want to alter that setting.

Comment: See also [Is there a keyboard shortcut in Insert mode to tell vim that I don't want to be inside a comment any more?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17878768).

Comment: You may also be interested in [this petition](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/EKDS1PP4rPo/ifLO6FFNqe4J) on the developer's mailing list: some people feel that this setting, `formatoptions=ro`, shouldn't be on by default since it is a user preference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you’re editing a file of the `vim` filetype, Vim might by default insert the comment character (in Vimscript, this would be `"`) at the beginning of each new line you enter after a comment. As already mentioned, this is a result of Vim’s `formatoptions` setting.

**To turn this behavior off in the current file,** run

```
:set formatoptions-=ro
```

**To turn it off by default,** add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set formatoptions-=ro
```

**To turn it off for Vimscript files,** add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
augroup filetype_vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType vim setlocal formatoptions-=ro
augroup END
```

`r` and `o` are options which can be given to `formatoptions`. For the full list of possible options, run `:help fo-table`.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is governed by the *formatoptions* variable.

Use `:h formatoptions` to find out more.

The following article might also be helpful: [Disable automatic comment insertion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_automatic_comment_insertion).

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work, regardless of your `formatoptions` settings.

`inoremap <CR> <CR><C-U>`

Answer (score 1):

what command are you using to insert below?

If you use the standard "o" keystroke while in Navigation mode, it should insert a new line immediately below whatever the cursor is on, and automatically place you into Insert mode, without inserting an extra "

Similarly an uppercase "O" will insert a new line above whatever line the cursor is on, and place you in insert mode.

Comment: I'm well aware of what "o" and "O" does.  However, whenever using comments in a file with the .vim extensions, vim creates an addition " at the start of a new line.  The " part is what I didn't understand.