# Stop Vim from auto-inserting comments on newlines permanently?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, comments

I want prevent Vim from following behavior: if I'm editing source code file and type a comment in Vim and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd>, it will automatically start the next line with `//`, so it looks like this:

```
// this is a comment
//
```

These commands: `:set formatoptions-=r`, `:set formatoptions-=o` help, but only when I run them in Vim, but when i put this line `set formatoptions-=or` to the end of my vimrc file and restart Vim nothing happens so I need run them manually from editor every time I open new file.

Why addition of aforementioned line to the vimrc file has no effect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19461862

Comment: Read the link glts put in as a comment Alexander, but you are probably bumping into a setlocal fo=... in one or more autoloaded FileType plugins.  Each filetype usually sets a default formatoptions, so you may have to track through ftplugin, either under ~/.vim/ftplugin or in the system files (here as /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin, but that will change by OS and release).